# Search using previous query's values

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am relatively new to Splunk, and I am attempting to perform a query like the following. The snippets below each step show some of what's been attempted.

1. Query for initial set of events containing a string value

```
* "string_value"
```

2. Get list of distinct values for a specific field returned from step 1

```
* "string_value" | stats list(someField)
```

3. Search for events containing any of the specific field's values returned from step 2

```
* "string_value" | stats list(someField) as myList | search someField in myList
```

I'm not entirely certain if this can be accomplished. I've read documents on subqueries, foreach, and various aggregate methods, though I am still uncertain on how to achieve what I need.

Other attempts:

```
someField IN [search * "string_value" | stats list(someField) as myList]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *can* sequentially build a search like this, but you're *likely* better off doing it this way:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp someField IN("my","list","of","values") "string_value"
| stats values(someField) as someField
```

The more you can put in your initial search, the better (in general)